# How to covert complex JSON to CSV using ChoETL

Tags: json, csv, choetl

I want to convert the following JSON to CSV:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Ref": "h123",
      "StartDate": "2023-01-01",
      "EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Person": {
        "Name": "Tester",
        "Email": "test@test.com",
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "AddressLine1": "1 avenue",
        "AddressLine2": null,
        "AddressLine3": null,
        "AddressLine4": null,
        "AddressLine5": null,
        "Zipcode": "100123"
      },
      "ExtraData": null,
      "ExtraData1": {
        "X": "x",
        "Y": "y",
        "Z": "z"
      }
    },
    {
      "Ref": "h1234",
      "StartDate": "2023-01-01",
      "EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Person": {
        "Name": "Tester1",
        "Email": "test@test.com",
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "AddressLine1": "2 avenue",
        "AddressLine2": null,
        "AddressLine3": null,
        "AddressLine4": null,
        "AddressLine5": null,
        "Zipcode": "100124"
      },
      "ExtraData": null,
      "ExtraData1": {
        "X": "x",
        "Y": "y",
        "Z": "z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the latest `ChoETL.JSON.NETStandard` and .NET6 (and .NET8)

```
using var reader = new ChoJSONReader("sample.json");
using var writer = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv").WithFirstLineHeader();
writer.Write(reader);
```

But the output CSV is just one row, assuming need more configuration.

```
Data_0_Ref,Data_0_StartDate,Data_0_EndDate,Data_0_Person_Name,Data_0_Person_Email,Data_0_Person_PhoneNumber,Data_0_Person_AddressLine1,Data_0_Person_AddressLine2,Data_0_Person_AddressLine3,Data_0_Person_AddressLine4,Data_0_Person_AddressLine5,Data_0_Person_Zipcode,Data_0_ExtraData,Data_0_ExtraData1_X,Data_0_ExtraData1_Y,Data_0_ExtraData1_Z,Data_1_Ref,Data_1_StartDate,Data_1_EndDate,Data_1_Person_Name,Data_1_Person_Email,Data_1_Person_PhoneNumber,Data_1_Person_AddressLine1,Data_1_Person_AddressLine2,Data_1_Person_AddressLine3,Data_1_Person_AddressLine4,Data_1_Person_AddressLine5,Data_1_Person_Zipcode,Data_1_ExtraData,Data_1_ExtraData1_X,Data_1_ExtraData1_Y,Data_1_ExtraData1_Z
h123,2023-01-01,2024-01-01,Tester,test@test.com,,1 avenue,,,,,100123,,x,y,z,h1234,2023-01-01,2024-01-01,Tester1,test@test.com,,2 avenue,,,,,100124,,x,y,z
```

What I expect is multiple rows without field index.

Also is it possible to configure so that switch between the `ExtraData` and `ExtraData1` include and don't include in the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to convert JSON to csv by `ExtraData1` child node. If yes, there is option out of the box to setup by this node to output as expected CSV

```
using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
       .WithJSONPath("Data")
       .Configure(c => c.DefaultArrayHandling = false)
       .Configure(c => c.FlattenNode = true)
       .Configure(c => c.UseNestedKeyFormat = true)
       .Configure(c => c.FlattenByNodeName = "ExtraData1")
      )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(Console.Out)
           .WithFirstLineHeader()
          )
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ref,StartDate,EndDate,Person_Name,Person_Email,Person_PhoneNumber,Person_AddressLine1,Person_AddressLine2,Person_AddressLine3,Person_AddressLine4,Person_AddressLine5,Person_Zipcode,ExtraData,ExtraData1_X,ExtraData1_Y,ExtraData1_Z
h123,2023-01-01,2024-01-01,Tester,test@test.com,,1 avenue,,,,,100123,,x,y,z
h1234,2023-01-01,2024-01-01,Tester1,test@test.com,,2 avenue,,,,,100124,,x,y,z
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7jjCPa

Comment: Thanks @Cinchoo, this gave me ideas to try more things.

Comment: Also how about nested array, e.g. in above example Person is an array, any settings to handle that?

Comment: flattenbymode work with only one node. If you can details out more details like expected output etc. that would be helpful. pls raise seperate request.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78182149/how-to-covert-json-with-nested-array-to-csv-using-choetl)