# How to covert JSON with nested array to CSV using ChoETL

Tags: c#, json, csv, choetl

I have a JSON file with nested array:

```
{
  "Member": [
    {
      "ExtractDate": "2024-03-18T13:29:50Z",
      "Information": {
        "Surname": "Smith",
        "FirstName": "John",
        "DateOfBirth": "1960-03-12",
        "Email": "test@test.com",
        "Telephone": "01234-123456",
        "Address": {
          "Line1": "1 Road",
          "Line2": "District",
          "Zipcode": "001555"
        },
        "Employment": [
          {
            "EmployerName": "AAA Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1988-04-01",
            "EndDate": "1990-10-15"
          },
          {
            "EmployerName": "ABC Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1991-01-25",
            "EndDate": "1995-11-30"
          }
        ]
      },
      "AdditionalInfo": [
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "AlternateName": "Name",
          "AdditionalMessage": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "AlternateName": "Name",
          "AdditionalMessage": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ExtractDate": "2024-03-18T13:29:50Z",
      "Information": {
        "Surname": "John",
        "FirstName": "Joe",
        "DateOfBirth": "1960-03-12",
        "Email": "test@test.com",
        "Telephone": "01234-123456",
        "Address": {
          "Line1": "1 Road",
          "Line2": "District",
          "Zipcode": "001555"
        },
        "Employment": [
          {
            "EmployerName": "AAA Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1988-04-01",
            "EndDate": "1990-10-15"
          },
          {
            "EmployerName": "ABC Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1991-01-25",
            "EndDate": "1995-11-30"
          }
        ]
      },
      "AdditionalInfo": [
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "AlternateName": "Name",
          "AdditionalMessage": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "AlternateName": "Name",
          "AdditionalMessage": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have mapped it to C# classes:

```
    public class AdditionalInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AlternateName")]
        public string AlternateName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AdditionalMessage")]
        public List<string> AdditionalMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [JsonProperty("Line1")]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Line2")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Zipcode")]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employment
    {
        [JsonProperty("EmployerName")]
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
        public string EmploymentStartDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
        public string EmploymentEndDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Information
    {
        [JsonProperty("Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Telephone")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Employment")]
        public List<Employment> Employment { get; set; }
    }

    public class Member
    {
        [JsonProperty("ExtractDate")]
        public DateTime ExtractDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Information")]
        public Information Information { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AdditionalInfo")]
        public List<AdditionalInfo> AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("Member")]
        public List<Member> Member{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use ChoETL to convert it to a CSV file.

I am expecting following output:

```
ExtractDate,Surname,FirstName,DateOfBirth,Email,Telephone,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,Zipcode,EmployerName,EmplymentStartDate,EmplymentStartEndDate,EmployerName2,EmplymentStartDate2,EmplymentStartEndDate2,Type,AlternateName,AdditionalMessage
2024-03-18 13:29:50,Smith,John,1960-03-12,test@test.com,01234-123456,1 Road,District,001555,AAA Ltd,1988-04-01,1990-10-15,ABC Ltd,1991-01-25,1995-11-30,A,Name,A+B+C
2024-03-18 13:29:50,John,Joe,1960-03-12,test@test.com,01234-123456,1 Road,District,001555,AAA Ltd,1988-04-01,1990-10-15,ABC Ltd,1991-01-25,1995-11-30,A,Name,A+B+C
```

Some of the field names are required to change if multiple items e.g. Employment, Employment2, Employment3 and so on. Some value is string concatenation e.g. A+B+C. How to configure ChoETL to meet such requirements.

Comment: this article should help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cinchoo-etl-converting-json-to-csv-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite complex ask, to convert the given JSON to expected CSV file. Will require lot of code lift to accomblish it.

**Step 1:** Create converters for `Employment` and `AdditionalInfo` members to handle the expected CSV output from them. Here are

*Employment Converter:*

```
public class EmploymentConverter : IChoValueConverter, IChoHeaderConverter, IChoCollectionConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var list = (value as ICollection<Employment>).Take(2).ToList();
        if (list.Count() < 2)
        {
            list.Add(new Employment());
        }
        return list.Select(f => new object[] { f.EmployerName, f.EmploymentStartDate, f.EmploymentEndDate }).Unfold().ToArray();
    }

    public string GetHeader(string name, string fieldName, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "EmployerName,EmplymentStartDate,EmplymentStartEndDate,EmployerName2,EmplymentStartDate2,EmplymentStartEndDate2";
    }

}
```

*AdditionalInfo Converter:*

```
public class AdditionalInfoConverter : IChoValueConverter, IChoHeaderConverter, IChoCollectionConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = (value as ICollection<AdditionalInfo>).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
            item = new AdditionalInfo();
        
        var list = new AdditionalInfo[] { item  };
        return list.Select(f => new object[] { f.Type, f.AlternateName, String.Join("+", f.AdditionalMessage) }).Unfold().ToArray();
    }

    public string GetHeader(string name, string fieldName, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Type,AlternateName,AdditionalMessage";
    }

}
```

**Step 2:** Decorate them to corresponding properties in POCO class

```
public class AdditionalInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AlternateName")]
    public string AlternateName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AdditionalMessage")]
    public List<string> AdditionalMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("Line1")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Line2")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Zipcode")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
}

public class Employment
{
    [JsonProperty("EmployerName")]
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
    public string EmploymentStartDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
    public string EmploymentEndDate { get; set; }
}

public class Information
{
    [JsonProperty("Surname")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DateOfBirth")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Telephone")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Employment")]
    [ChoTypeConverter(typeof(EmploymentConverter))]
    [ChoCSVRecordField(QuoteField = false)]
    public List<Employment> Employment { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    [JsonProperty("ExtractDate")]
    public DateTime ExtractDate { get; set; }

    [ChoCSVRecordField]
    [JsonProperty("Information")]
    public Information Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AdditionalInfo")]
    [ChoTypeConverter(typeof(AdditionalInfoConverter))]
    [ChoCSVRecordField(QuoteField = false)]
    public List<AdditionalInfo> AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 3:** Finally using ChoETL, you can convert JSON to CSV as below

```
using (var r = ChoJSONReader<Member>.LoadText(json)
       .WithJSONPath("Member")
       .Configure(c => c.FlattenByNodeName = "Information")
        .UseJsonSerialization()
      )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter<Member>(Console.Out)
           .WithFirstLineHeader()
           .Configure(c => c.TypeConverterFormatSpec.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
          )
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }

}
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G5pKSf

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. If there are many members in the Json and each member have different number of employments, some only have 2, some might have 10, and don't know what's the max number might get. In this scenario how to setup the csv header dynamically, is it have to find out the max number from the json first?

Comment: well, in that case, you will have to call out what is the max number of employments JSON file can carry or you need spec out max allowed employments in a JSON file. Because CSV is fixed format. you must figure out the nujmber of columns CSV can carry when writing.

Comment: Sure, have to set a max number. Also in terms of maintenance, if requirements change e.g. csv header names change, code change is inevitable, not something can be put into a separate configuration file.